# Failed to sync gradle project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-play-services

I am unable to sync the Basic Samples project from `Google Play Services`. I have tried updating the `minsdk`, `targetsdk`, `compilesdk` versions, updated the project structure and flavors but the project still won't `sync`.

This is my error:

```
Error:Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0] on DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='com.android.support', name='appcompat-v7', version='24.2.0', configuration='default'} of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultExternalModuleDependency.

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>
```

However I installed the latest `Android Support Repository (rev 36)` so I assume the issue is something else.

If you want to try and clone the project: https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples.git

`gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'
    defaultConfig {

        /*
          REPLACE THIS VALUE WITH YOUR APPLICATION ID
        */
        applicationId "com.google.example.games.replace.me"

        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${appcompat_library_version}" compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${support_library_version}" compile project(':libraries:BaseGameUtils')
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is actually a fairly minor one: you don't have end-lines after each dependency.

This

```
dependencies {
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${appcompat_library_version}" compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${support_library_version}" compile project(':libraries:BaseGameUtils')
}
```

should be

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${appcompat_library_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${support_library_version}"
    compile project(':libraries:BaseGameUtils')
}
```

This error is quite common when a plugin on Android Studio edits or modifies the gradle file in any way when the dependency uses a variable instead of a direct reference to the version number. For instance, I've noticed this happen to me when using the Method Counts plugin or even the Firebase plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got a work around:

I removed this section from the basic samples gradle file

```
ext {
    android_compile_version = 24
    android_version = '24.0.1'
    android_min_sdk_version = 19

    appcompat_library_version = '24.2.0'
    support_library_version = '24.2.0'
    gms_library_version = '9.4.0'
}
```

and removed this from the other gradle files:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${appcompat_library_version}" 
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${support_library_version}"         
    compile project(':libraries:BaseGameUtils')
}
```

and replaced them with the actual values.

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0" 
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0"         
    compile project(':libraries:BaseGameUtils')
}
```

Somehow this made all the difference

**EDIT**

The problem actually was not having end-lines after each dependency! Don't write all your dependencies on the same line

Problem in `gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
   compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${appcompat_library_version}" compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${support_library_version}" compile project(':libraries:BaseGameUtils')
}
```

Solution:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0" 
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0"         
    compile project(':libraries:BaseGameUtils')
}
```

Comment: Surely you did something else because all you did was remove some string variables.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following code in your project's `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

My project was missing the Google's Maven Repo URL. Added it and gradle synced like a charm.

Hope it saves someone's time.